# Struggling to clone animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development

I am trying to create a linear animation with pipes just like the flappy bird game. When I have one single pipe, I see a random gap and it works well, but when I clone all the pipes, there is no longer a gap at a random position.

**How can I give the gaps in the pipe a random position when I have multiple pipes, and why is it not working as expected?**

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");
//clone the pipe multiples times
var blockClone;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  blockClone = block.cloneNode(true);
  // the true is for deep cloning

  //append all clones to original pipe                          
  block.appendChild(blockClone);
  //remove animtion from clones
  blockClone.style.animationName = "none";
}
//gap inbetween each pipe
var hole = document.getElementById("hole");
var holeClone;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  holeClone = hole.cloneNode(true);
  // the true is for deep cloning

  //append all clones to original pipe                          
  blockClone.appendChild(hole);
  block.appendChild(hole);
  //remove animtion from clones
  holeClone.style.animationName = "none";
  hole.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
    var random = -((Math.random() * 300) + 150);
    hole.style.top = random + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#game {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* pipe version 1 */

#block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url("https://l.dropbox.com/s/4jz7uq4e25o8su5/sketch-1664244879.png?dl=0");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  animation: block 5s infinite linear;
}

#hole {
  width: 60px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -10px;
  /* animation: block 5s infinite
           linear;*/
  background-image: url("https://dldropbox.com/s/j7enawgtuepj7au/sketch-166428805830.png?dl=0");
  background-size: cover;
}

#character {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
  border-radius: ;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}


}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
}

/* used to prevent user from tapping even after the game has ended*/
.mainoverlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
#blokhold {
  animation: block 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 350px
  }
  
  100% {
    left: -890px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="game">
  <div id="blokhold">
    <div id="block">
      <div id="hole"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="character"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). You’re just moving the same `hole` object to different places while your `holeClone`s are not used in the DOM at all. You’re confusing `holeClone` with `hole` in several places. There’s only one `hole`.